# EclipseCORBA without compilation?

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, corba, idl

I am using EclipseCORBA, but mostly just for syntax highlighting. I'm wondering if there is a way to turn off the IDL compiler. The reason being that it doesn't bring up valid errors in my IDL files.

Alternative eclipse plugins to EclipseCORBA for syntax highlighting IDL files (ideally one with a formatter :> ) are also welcome. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the solution to this, but if you have an EBNF grammar for IDL - that shouldn't be too difficult to find - then [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) could be an "easy" way to create an editor. The formatter would be a little extra work, but...

Comment: CORBA IDL grammar is available in this PDF (see section 3.4): http://www.ing.iac.es/~docs/external/corba/idl-spec.pdf

Comment: I'm awarding this as the answer, because while it didn't really answer my question, there might not be a real answer, and this might be the closest answer available.